# Chrome and Edge Selenium crashes after the for-loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing an automation script that would facilitate job application process. What I want to do is to open several new tabs within a browser and then successively apply for them. All was going well until the browser shuts down after successfully completing the iteration without raising any exceptions. I want to keep the tabs open so I can apply for the job ads and make a record of it.

I have already tried adding additional time space to accommodate for page load-up; cookies deleteion is out of quesiton because I have to be logged in. Additionally, I have reduced the number of links. Tested on MS Edge and Chrome.

The "get_links" function delivers corresponding links to job ads.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
delay = 5

# Job Preferences
preferences = {
    "position-title" : "financial analyst"
    }

# URLs
url_home = "https://www.reed.co.uk"
# url_example = """https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/financial-analyst-jobs?pageno=1"""

# Logging In
browser.get(url_home)

try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]""")) 
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("the page has not loaded up.")

cookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]""")
cookies.click()

signIn_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="site-header"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a""")
signIn_button.click()

try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="signin_email"]""")) 
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("the page has not loaded up.")

username_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="signin_email"]""")
username_.send_keys("email")

password_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="signin_password"]""")
password_.send_keys("password")

signIn_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="signin_button"]""")
signIn_.click()

# Query search after having logged in.
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="keywords"]""")) 
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("the page has not loaded up.")

search_query = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="keywords"]""")
search_query.send_keys(preferences.get("position-title"))

search_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="main-search"]/div[1]/div[3]/button""")
search_button.click()

# Filters and job type selection
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="refine-salary-from"]""")) 
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("the page has not loaded up.")

salaryRange = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="refine-salary-from"]"""))
salaryRange.select_by_value('28000')

browser.implicitly_wait(2)

parent_tab = browser.current_window_handle

for link_ in get_links.get_joblinks(url_home, browser.current_url).Link[0:5]:
    sleep(2)
    browser.execute_script('''window.open("{}");'''.format(link_))
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: maybe you should run `sleep(very_long_time)` or endless loop - `while True: pass` - to keep script working all time. Maybe it automatically closes browser when script is closed (some kind of `garbage collection` - when parent program is closed then its child program is also close)

Comment: Thank you, it has helped me as well as adding extra time (sleep.time()). Turns out the driver was crashing becasue it could not have found the required elements.